# ObjectDataSource Paging with Non Numeric StartRowIndexParameter

Tags: asp.net

Not really too sure how to explain this so I might be a bit wafferly here, but I would still appreiciate any help I can get.

What I've got to work with is a COM data source.  I can pass querys to this COM data source (SQL Syntax)  which will then return me a COM object  it's effectively an unindexed list.  Using this returned com object, I'm able to iterrate through and parse individual records into .net friendly typed objects.
This is all very simple and works quite well when accessing single records.   However there are a few places where i want to display lists of records such as on a grid etc. When
I start getting more and more records returned when the parsing really starts to slow the whole process down,  What would be ideal is to implement some sort of lazy or on-demand loading

So I've been looking at the ObjectDataSource and using Paging.  I'm resonably sure that this would do exaxctly what I want execpt that don't have any access to any sort of row counters/record enumumators.  What I do have is the the primary key for the datasource which is a string type which I can sort by.

What I'm asking is this.  Is there a way to implement a selectcount method on a object datasource where the StartRowIndexParameter isn't a integer?